# Issues communicating with devices over usb hub

Tags: usb, microcontroller, descriptor

I'm facing issues when communicating with devices over USB hub. When enumerating devices directly to host port, it does work, some devices over usb hub have issues.

Setup: STM32F103C8 - MAX3421E - LUFA (usb stack) (ported to MAX3421E (host) and STM32F103C8T6 (device)) - USB Full-Speed setup

Scenario:
When I attach device directly to host, I don't experience any issues enumerating almost all (some devices seems to be faulty and have weird/nonstandard behavior) devices. But when I try to enumerate over usb hub, devices starts to behave very strangely. I'm receiving much more NAK's from devices than when connected directly to host. Some devices are able to return Device Descriptor, but retrieving Configuration Descriptor fail. Some devices return Toggle Error after several NAK's, this could be remedied so far by delaying retry IN token. Also there is different behavior of devices when connected over different hubs. I.e. one device has no problems when connected to HUB1, but have issues when connected to HUB2. Then I have HUB3 (7 port) which internally acts as HUB in HUB. On this HUB3 device working fine on port behind secondary internal hub, but not on primary ports exposed over "root" hub.

I'm in suspicion that hub's TT could be somehow interfering with usb communication, but according to information I have found, TT should not be enabled under Full-Speed setup.

I have checked (many times) that I'm setting correct device address assigned during SetAddress phase (which is proved by returning Device Descriptor). When I step debug it seems that I can get Configuration Descriptor also, but while in normal system run, it isn't retrieved, but only over hub.

Does anyone has any ideas, what to look after? I've run out of ideas here after week of trying to find a root cause.

Thanks

Comment: You said, "TT should not be enabled under Full-Speed setup". Thats inaccurate. TT will be used to isolate HS signalling from FS/LS signalling using split transaction. Can you please share your source for this info?

Comment: I have no direct link, but I'm under impression, that while hub is not connected to High-Speed host (which in my case isn't), split transaction are not needed. Also checked that devices connected to hub are not low speed which would need to send HUBPREPID, but I can retrieve Device Descriptor but not further on some devices.

Comment: Ok so host, hub, devices all are FS? In that case, yes TT is not required.

Comment: Yes, my whole chain is FS, but I suspect TT for doing some unwanted buffering. Those Toggle-Errors are really strange.

Comment: TT component should not be even present in FS hub as far as I know. TT component is included only in HS hub. So we can remove TT from the discussion completely. Could this be some silicon issue with the hub? Does that hub work fine with PC? Have you captured the trace by any chance? Generally toggle errors should not come. USB bus trace should give some idea.

Comment: Most probably the toggle errors are due to Corrupted ACK.

Comment: I'm considering electrical issues on usb bus now. Toggle errors could be most probably caused by distorted/noisy signals, though it sometimes looks like some packet buffering is active (that is my suspicion about TT buffers active somehow out of specs). What is confusing me, is that all devices around are enumerated properly without hub, connected directly to host. Over hub/s some are problematic, mostly in consistent way. I can imagine some electrical properties on boundary levels, but that consistency over different hubs is strange. Shouldn't be downstream ports separated from upstream port?

Comment: One thing, hubs are 2.0 HighSpeed, but chain is FullSpeed only.

Comment: Data toggle errors are called when your PID is out of sync between host and device. Are you talking about that or some other toggle error? Electrical issues, can cause missing/corrupted ACK and the device toggles its PID due to the electrical issue which in turn can make the host and device go out of sync.

Comment: I think its best if you get USB trace between device and hub and hub and host separately. That can tell you what could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

so...
- as usual after searching for root cause, solution after days of trying comes naturally after asking on somewhere (this is hapenning to me always, but I do try prior asking always)
- when using hubs, make sure you don't suspend SOF generation during control transfers. LUFA just resume bus inside control transfer routines, so make sure you don"t stops and reenable SOF within (my fault as I'm using ported version to MAX)
- if you have tight main loop make sure you don"t reinitialize usb transfer without completion of previous try, but if you do so, check you don't owerwrite data which haven"t been processed yet fully (especially when using interrupt-driven transfer complete processing) [things seems to work when you have quite some debug output, as it delay that time critical transfers]

Enumeration over hub isuues are now second to none. Small glitches are subject for tweaking.

Unfortunately as I was in question for electrical issues, I had to unsolder usb host shield and soldered another one, which in light of new information seems unneeded. Nevermind, I have trained my soldering skills.

Comment: Can you describe the reason for PID toggle? Also what do you mean by "dont suspend SOF generation"? Why would anyone do that? The moment your device gets connected, SOF starts automatically right? Until you stop the controller or suspend the bus, why SOF will stop?

Comment: Every problem comes from me turning SOF off during control request. As I ported LUFA to different chip (MAX3421E), I had wrongfully disabled SOF, then initiated resume and then renabled SOF in USB_Host_ResumeBus(). As LUFA doesn't check if bus isn't suspended at some places during requests, bus has been suspended. In single host scenario this isn't an issue, but with devices over hub it is. It was my fault, so my post is maybe for someone facing similar issues potentially to check this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... :)